# URL changes but components not rendered on navigation in Angular

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-routing

I am trying to make routing through simple components through button click in Angular app
I can see the url path is changing but the contents within the component's view is not rendered.
I created app with routing module(app-routing.module.ts)
I am trying to navigate to components named one , two from app.component.html through buttons.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tan';

  constructor(private router: Router) { }  

    openOne(){
      this.router.navigate(['/one']);
      console.log("inside gotopath func")
    
    }
    openTwo(){
      this.router.navigate(['/two']);
      console.log("inside gotopath func")
    
    }

  
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="openOne()">ONE</button>     
<button (click)="openTwo()">TWO</button>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './two/two.component';

const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'one', component: OneComponent},{ path: 'two', component: TwoComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './two/two.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OneComponent,
    TwoComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[AppRoutingModule,RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

one.component.html:

```
<p>one works!</p>
```

two.component.html

```
<p>two works!</p>
```

[1st page with buttons to navigate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiKMZ.png)

after clicking on ONE button

[after clicking ONE button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/657WB.png)

after clicking on TWO button
[after clicking TWO button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZYrG.png)

while hovering over buttons it is not showing url path in the left bottom.
I tried by removing all chrome extensions,
disabling "Enable Javascript source maps" and "Enable css source map" in dev tool settings as suggested in stack overflow.

I am getting this error after sometime:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr9of.png)

Earlier I often got this error:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received.

and this:

[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!

[error after sometime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUuR.png)

Please help me resolve this I am trying this for many days :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want content to change dynamically based on the current route, then you need to add [Router Outlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet) in your root component (root component is `app.component` in your case). For example:

**app.component.ts**

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<!-- Display content for current route -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Note that you should not place buttons which redirect to other components (or any other HTML) inside root component (`app.component.html`). Instead, create a new component (for example `ParentComponent`) which will display your required buttons.

**parent.component.ts**

```
// parent.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  openOne(){
    console.log("inside openOne func");
    this.router.navigate(['/one']);
  
  }
  openTwo(){
    console.log("inside openTwo func");
    this.router.navigate(['/two']);
  
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```html
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<button (click)="openOne()">ONE</button>     
<button (click)="openTwo()">TWO</button>
```

Now goto your routing module and set default path to this parent component.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './two/two.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './parent/parent.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ParentComponent },
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent},
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```